# How do I ignore unused warnings in quasiquotes?

Tags: scala, suppress-warnings, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I have a macro that is using quasiquotes like:

```scala
    accessor.tree match {
      // FIXME: Get rid of the unused warning here.
      case q"($source) => $rhs" => validate(rhs, hasSelect = false)
      case t                    => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Invalid function expression ${show(t)}")
    }
```

This gives me the following warnings:

```
[warn] /Users/jason/source/goodcover/core/macros/src/main/scala/webm/react/syntax/StableFieldOpsImpl.scala:36:12: pattern var qq$macro$1 in method unapply is never used: use a wildcard `_` or suppress this warning with `qq$macro$1@_`
[warn]       case q"($source) => $rhs" => validate(rhs, hasSelect = false)
[warn]            ^
[warn] /Users/jason/source/goodcover/core/macros/src/main/scala/webm/react/syntax/StableFieldOpsImpl.scala:36:16: pattern var source in method validateSelection is never used: use a wildcard `_` or suppress this warning with `source@_`
[warn]       case q"($source) => $rhs" => validate(rhs, hasSelect = false)
[warn]                ^
[warn] two warnings found
```

Using a wildcard doesn't work:

```scala
    accessor.tree match {
      // FIXME: Get rid of the unused warning here.
      case q"(_) => $rhs" => validate(rhs, hasSelect = false)
      case t              => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Invalid function expression ${show(t)}")
    }
```

That fails with:

```
[error] /Users/jason/source/goodcover/core/macros/src/main/scala/webm/react/syntax/StableFieldOpsImpl.scala:36:18: ';' expected but '=>' found.
[error]       case q"(_) => $rhs" => validate(rhs, hasSelect = false)
[error]                  ^
[error] /Users/jason/source/goodcover/core/macros/src/main/scala/webm/react/syntax/StableFieldOpsImpl.scala:36:12: extractor macros can only expand into extractor calls
[error]       case q"(_) => $rhs" => validate(rhs, hasSelect = false)
[error]            ^
[error] two errors found
```

I don't know what `` suppress this warning with `source@_` `` means.

If I take it literally as in:

```scala
    accessor.tree match {
      // FIXME: Get rid of the unused warning here.
      case q"(source@_) => $rhs" => validate(rhs, hasSelect = false)
      case t                     => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Invalid function expression ${show(t)}")
    }
```

Then I get:

```
[error] /Users/jason/source/goodcover/core/macros/src/main/scala/webm/react/syntax/StableFieldOpsImpl.scala:36:21: ')' expected but '@' found.
[error]       case q"(source@_) => $rhs" => validate(rhs, hasSelect = false)
[error]                     ^
[error] /Users/jason/source/goodcover/core/macros/src/main/scala/webm/react/syntax/StableFieldOpsImpl.scala:36:12: extractor macros can only expand into extractor calls
[error]       case q"(source@_) => $rhs" => validate(rhs, hasSelect = false)
[error]            ^
[error] two errors found
```

How do I ignore these warnings?

Comment: Did you try if something like `q"(${_}) => $rhs"` (or `q"($_) => $rhs"`) works? –

Comment: *"I don't know what ``suppress this warning with `source@_` `` means"* Try `case q"(${source@_}) => $rhs" => ...`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but adding

```scala
scalacOptions += "-Ywarn-macros:after"
```

makes the warning disappeared in my case.